# Evaluar si hay un cambio de valor entre múltiples columnas

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe con ocho columnas que simboliza el tipo de mascarilla que ha utilizado cada paciente (Entrega 1, 2,3, etc) y otra columna con el número de usuario.

Para evitar saturar la pregunta os muestro aquí un extracto con múltiples supuestos de lo que es la tabla.

```
     Usuario    Entrega 1      Entrega 2    Entrega 3
       5           o                NA          NA
       10          FF               FF          O
       12          FF               FF          FF
       20          N                FF          FF
```

Cada paciente puede utilizar un tipo de mascarilla hasta el final, cambiar, o simplemente que no exista registro hasta el final.

En cualquier caso, lo que me gustaría saber es si es posible añadir una nueva columna que signifique 1 "cambio" y 0 "no cambio" para cada uno de los pacientes dependiendo de si ha cambiado o no de mascarilla (independientmente de que tenga registro hasta el final o no).

¿Existe alguna función que permita evaluar si hay un cambio de valor entre múltiples columnas?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con R base simplemente cuentas por fila los valores únicos de las columnas de interés, ignorando los `NA`:

```
df$cambio <- apply(
              df[, 2:4], 1, 
              FUN=function(x) length(unique(na.omit(unlist(x))))
              ) > 1

  Usuario Entrega 1 Entrega 2 Entrega 3 cambio
1       5         o      <NA>      <NA>  FALSE
2      10        FF        FF         O   TRUE
3      12        FF        FF        FF  FALSE
4      20         N        FF        FF   TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución que se me ocurre con tidyverse es la siguiente:

Llevar a formato Long los datos:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("Entrega"),
               names_to = "Tipo_Entrega",
               values_to = "Valor_Entrega")

# A tibble: 12 x 3
   Usuario Tipo_Entrega Valor_Entrega
     <dbl> <chr>        <chr>        
 1       5 Entrega_1    o            
 2       5 Entrega_2    NA           
 3       5 Entrega_3    NA           
 4      10 Entrega_1    FF           
 5      10 Entrega_2    FF           
 6      10 Entrega_3    0            
 7      12 Entrega_1    FF           
 8      12 Entrega_2    FF           
 9      12 Entrega_3    FF           
10      20 Entrega_1    N            
11      20 Entrega_2    FF           
12      20 Entrega_3    FF
```

Agrupar por usuario y generar la variable cambios, que sera "no", cuando los valores distintos para cada valor de entrega sea 1, y "si" en caso contrario

```
df = df %>%
  group_by(Usuario) %>%
  mutate(cambios = ifelse(n_distinct(Valor_Entrega,na.rm = T) == 1, "no", "si")) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Finalmente retomar el formato Ancho, recuperando la variable cambios

```
df = df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Tipo_Entrega,
              values_from = Valor_Entrega)

# A tibble: 4 x 5
  Usuario cambios Entrega_1 Entrega_2 Entrega_3
    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
1       5 no      o         NA        NA       
2      10 si      FF        FF        0        
3      12 no      FF        FF        FF       
4      20 si      N         FF        FF
```

Comment: Las dos respuestas son más que válidas. Pero he de elegir una como solución del problema. Dado que la de @Patricio Moracho conlleva menos pasos me decanto por ella. Muchas gracias a los dos.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo otra forma muy simplificada también usando solo tidyverse

```
df %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(cambios = n_distinct(c_across(contains("Entrega")), na.rm = T) > 1)
```